# SQL Cut string to second uppercase letter (Postgres)

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, trim, concatenation

So i have a column that contains `FirstnameSecondname` (Not separated). The first letters of both names are uppercase. I would need to divide these values up in separate columns - `Firstname`, `Secondname` and `Fullname` (Where both of these parts of the string are divided with space). But as I would be able to concatenate the individual parts together it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: `select x[1] as n1, x[2] as n2 from regexp_matches('FirstnameSecondname','([A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)') as t(x);`

Comment: Works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases SQL Server consider strings (varchar) as case-insensitive so you need to set case sensitive collation explicitly. Next you have to find *last* uppercase letter and use this position. Altogether

```
declare @a varchar(50)='FirstnameSecondname'
select reverse(
         left(reverse(@a),
              PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',
                reverse(@a collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN)))) secondname
```

Use similar tricks for Firstname